# pandas or postgres table - how to convert string currency values e.g. "£300k"

Tags: pandas, postgresql

I have a table with a currency field that is currently formatted as a string, e.g. "£1.5m". How can I convert the column to the equivalent numeric value, i.e. 1,500,000?

The data is in postgres so I could either cast it in the table, or convert using pandas. I'm currently trying in pandas. I'd ideally like to understand how to it either way.

I've tried using pandas `to_numeric`, but it is unable to parse the value.

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
     'name': ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
     'assets': ["£472.96k", "£142.6m", "£500", "-£3.38m"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['assets'] = pd.to_numeric(['assets'])
```

EDIT - the code below works for pandas.

Would be interested in the postgres approach though

```py
def convert_column(Col):
    Col = Col.str.replace('£', '')
    Col = (Col.replace(r'[km]+$', '', regex=True).astype(float) * \
                Col.str.extract(r'[\d\.]+([km]+)', expand=False)
                .fillna(1)
                .replace(['k','m'], [10**3, 10**6]).astype(int))
    return Col

for col in ['assets']:
    df[col] = convert_column(df[col])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Postgres solution is completely doable, it requires 1 SQL statement. The following implements such a solution. The query assumes an array of strings for input. Then beginning it shows each step (through sub select) to derive the asset value.

1. Separate (Unnest) the array into individual elements.
2. Discard the currency symbol (£).
3. Split out via regular expression the numeric value and the magnitude
   (k,m) codes.
4. Apply the magnitude code to the numeric value for final value.
5. Along the way, keep the original value and at the last if is not a
   valid value to begin with output a null value.

```
with test(assets) as 
     ( values (array ['£472.96k', '£142.6m', '£500', '-£3.38m' , 'xxx'] ) )
   , exp(re) as 
     ( values ('^(\+|-)?([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)(m|k)?$'))
 
select orig_asset 
     , case when assets ~ re 
            then case when asset_mag = 'k'
                      then asset_val * 1000::float
                      when asset_mag = 'm'
                      then asset_val * 1000000::float
                      else asset_val
                 end 
            else null
       end asset_value
  from (select orig_asset,assets, re
             , regexp_replace (assets, re,'\1\2')::float asset_val 
             , regexp_replace (assets, re,'\3')          asset_mag
          from exp cross join
               ( select  assets orig_asset 
                      ,  replace(assets,'£','') assets
                   from ( select unnest(assets) assets from test) a
               ) b
       ) c;
```

Finally, you can wrap the whole query into a SQL function that returns a table. The result of which can be used like any table is a query. See [fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3ee9fe4c45025d657878a6f13edad8f6) for an example of each